# Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, voximplant

```
// No problem at all with this code
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'
const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                Test
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default App

OUTPUT: LOG  Running "Chat" with {"rootTag":161,"initialProps":{}}
info Reloading app...
 BUNDLE  ./index.js 

********************************************

// but as soon as I import

import {View, Text} from 'react-native'
import {Voximplant} from 'react-native-voximplant';  <--

const client = Voximplant.getInstance();   <--

const App = () => {
    
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                Test
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default App


// I get the following.
OUTPUT: LOG  Running "Chat" with {"rootTag":171,"initialProps":{}}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
```

I have try all the latest answers on GitHub and stack overflow but none of them work. At this point I don't know what to do. Do to this problem I am not able to use Voximplant.

{
"name": "Chat",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"lint": "eslint .",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.5",
"react-native-voximplant": "^1.36.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
"@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
"@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
"@types/react": "^18.0.24",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
"eslint": "^8.19.0",
"jest": "^29.2.1",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
"prettier": "^2.4.1",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "4.8.4"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}

Currently running on MacBook Pro M2, OS: macOs Ventura Version 13.3

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, did you run `pod install` in your ios folder after adding the new module?

That looks like an error when you install a new module but don't generate the pods for the iOS development.

Steps:

1. Navigate to your ios folder within your react-native project.
2. run `pod install` from the terminal.
3. On Xcode, clean your project by using the shortcut `cmd+shift+k`. (Pro tip: you can delete the Derived Data folder within ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData, it will be generated again once you successfully build your app).
4. Build your app (`cmd+r`);

Comment: 1. I have 'npm install react-native-voximplant —save'
2. I went to the iOS folder within react-native project
3. I have executed 'pod install'.

$ Pod installation complete! There are 60 dependencies from the Podfile and 52    total  pods installed.

4. I have open the project with Xcode and clean with cmd+shift+k
5. I have build the app with cmd+r
6. I have run the project one more time.

$ LOG  Running "ChatY" with {"rootTag":151,"initialProps":{}}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

Still does not work.

Comment: It looks that there are many unsolved questions with the same error. At this point I don't know if react-native module it self or Voximplant.